# Bootstrap-Carousel not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to load a simple html page with a carousel but the carousel does not fit the screen. Here is a screenshot:
[Html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhR7V.png)

And below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Carousel / Slider</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- My Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="my-slider"class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                    <!-- Indicators dot nav -->

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="images/apple.jpg" alt="Fruits"/>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Assorted Fruits</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Controls Next Prev buttons  -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is making the carousel to not fit the screen. I'm just beginning to learn frontend so if anyone could give a detailed explanation, I would be grateful.

EDIT: This is what it looks like if I add more than one picture to the carousel: [The same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNsgf.png)

Comment: Close your head tag mate before <div class="container">

Comment: I've done that. Still no difference

Comment: Can you update your code then. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I've updated it but I don't know what fiddle is :)

Comment: Put your code up on Bootply.com - it's a testing playground for Bootstrap.  If you're using v4 Alpha you'll need to adjust the settings to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [working design](https://codepen.io/HebleV/pen/zdKKwB).

You have missed a lot of code due to which it makes unworkable and also I didn't see the code for the second image. Rule is you will have to include all the images inside its respective  `class="item"`.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
     <div class="item active">
       <img src="one.jpg" alt="...">
     </div>
     <div class="item>
        <img src="two.jpg" alt="...">
     </div>
</div>
```

This example was using data-attributes (data-ride="carousel"). You can also achieve this using Java script by calling carousel class manually `$('.carousel').carousel()`

**Important Note** : Always include Jquery before the bootstrap.js(or any library) file to avoid any bugs.

Answer (score -1):

you html seems invalid the scripts tags should be on the head tag close to your stylesheet, another thing that that you forgot to close the head and open de body

Comment: Montiero Please look at the edit. The images of the carousel stack on top of one another

Comment: sorry, I edited the answer, seems that your html structure it's invalid try close you head and open the body and move the script tags inside to the head

Comment: Thanks for the tags but still no difference

Comment: do you moved the script tag to up?

Comment: Yes I did. Still no difference

Comment: Can you do a ctrl+shift+J to open the console, then do refresh and paste here the errors?

Comment: use <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> under the footer before the closing </body>